# Airflow Cloud composer to load the parquet file into BigQuery as Appended schemas - Issue with one column not able to load particular one column only

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to load parquet file data from GCS to BigQuery as an append column.

I am able to append the schemas in BigQuery, but there is one column which is not loading/appearing in my final BigQuery.

Below is the code which I am using:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import datetime,time
from airflow import DAG,models
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators import dummy_operator
import logging
import json,os
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.sensors.bigquery import (
    BigQueryTableExistenceSensor,
    BigQueryTablePartitionExistenceSensor,
)
from airflow.utils import timezone


yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': yesterday
        
}

with models.DAG(
        'Parquet_GCS_to_BQ',
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False,
        #schedule_interval='* 5 * * * ') as dag: 
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    start = dummy_operator.DummyOperator(
        task_id='start',
        trigger_rule='all_success'
    )

    end = dummy_operator.DummyOperator(
        task_id='end',
        trigger_rule='all_success'
    )
   
    
    GCS_to_BQ = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id='Loading_Parquet_Into_BQ',
            bucket='my bucket',
            source_objects=['path/to/parquet/year=2021/month=8/*.parquet',  'path/to/parquet/year=2022/month=9/*.parquet'],
            source_format='parquet',
            destination_project_dataset_table='project_name.dataset_name.table_name',
            create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
            write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
            schema_update_options=['ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION', 'ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION'],
            autodetect=True,
            skip_leading_rows=1,
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
            bigquery_conn_id='google_cloud_default'
        )
  
    start >> GCS_to_BQ >> end
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you confirm that the column exists in the source parquet?

Comment: All the columns on your `parquet` are not added to the `Biguery` table ?

Comment: @RNHTTR yes , the columns exists in the source parquet file , the column name is account_feature_brand , apart from this column there are several other columns which is have different column in different different files. Not sure why this column is not only populating in the bigquery, Is anything wrong in my code?? If someone will ask you to write a dag to load the data in the bigquery  as an appended column what would be your code? Could anyone provide their own code maybe it will work for me

Comment: @MazlumTosun Yes I am able to add all the other columns in the BogQuery table except this one perticular column- account_features_bran.

Comment: --------Scenario 1----
Day1 File:
ee-nba-prd-cnba-traceability/traceability-v3/year=2021/month=8/file1.parquet --> empid,empname,salary
Day1 BigQuery:
sl_dim_parquet --> empid,empname,salary
Day2 File:
ee-nba-prd-cnba-traceability/traceability-v3/year=2022/month=9/file2.parquet --> empid,empname,account_features_brand,address,zipcode
Day2 BigQuery:
sl_dim_parquet --> empid,empname,salary,address,zipcode

Note: I need to appended columns in the same table itself 
If you will see in Day2 , it is not appending the column-account_features_brand ,Ideally it should append.

Comment: ------Scenario 2-----------
Day1 File:
ee-nba-prd-cnba-traceability/traceability-v3/year=2022/month=9/file2.parquet --> empid,empname,account_features_brand,address,zipcode
Day1 BigQuery:
sl_dim_parquet --> empid,empname,account_features_brand,address,zipcode
Day2 File:
ee-nba-prd-cnba-traceability/traceability-v3/year=2021/month=8/file1.parquet --> empid,empname,salary
Day2 BigQuery:
sl_dim_parquet --> empid,empname,account_features_brand,address,zipcode,salary

Comment: ----Scenario3---------------
Day1 File:
ee-nba-prd-cnba-traceability/traceability-v3/year=2022/month=9/file2.parquet --> empid,empname,account_features_brand,address,zipcode
ee-nba-prd-cnba-traceability/traceability-v3/year=2021/month=8/file1.parquet --> empid,empname,salary
Day1 BigQuery:
sl_dim_parquet --> empid,empname,address,zipcode,salary

Comment: Observation from above 3 scenarios - Note: In scenario2 , I am able to load the column-account_features_brand ,but why I am not able to load the column-account_features_brand
in scenario1 when the column is coming in Day2